# How the compilation process pick the right source file?

Tags: compiler-construction, makefile, mpi

I am looking at a Makefile to figure out my question. My question is there are two directories included in the compilation which have fortran source files with exactly the same name, how the compilation itself decide which source file to use. As for my case, the two directories are /dir1/ and /dir2/. Both have a fortran file named test.F90 file and both directories are included as include directories. Then why /dir1/test.F90 is compiled rather than /dir2/test.F90. The Makefile code extract are

```
 SOURCES := $(shell cat Srcfiles)
 OBJS    := $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SOURCES)))

 .F90.o:
    $(FC) -c $(INCLDIR) $(INCS) $(FFLAGS) $(FREEFLAGS)  $<
```

Part of the real compilation looks like:

```
mpif90 -c -I/dir1/ -I/dir2 ... /dir1/test.F90
```

in the Srcfiles, there is list of all the Fortran files as

```
test.F90
test1.F90
...
```

There is also a file called Filepath which lists file directories as

```
/dir1/
/dir2/
/dir3/
```

I provide as much as I think related to my question and could you point to direction how can I solve my question?

Comment: How is `INCLDIR` formed? Also, it's unclear what is the rule for building your target, i.e. which object files are required. Is that just `OBJS`? (I doubt that.)

Comment: *"I provide as much as I think related to my question..."* Clearly you did not provide enough. Please post the whole makefile. And do you want to know how Make chooses `dir1/test.F90`, or how to get Make to use `dir2/test.F90`?

Answer (score 2):

This makefile builds files named `xxx.o` from files named `xxx.F90`.  `xxx` can be a simple filename, or it can be a pathname; it doesn't matter.

The makefile gets a list of files to build from the `Srcfiles` file (via `cat`).  So, in your `Srcfiles` file you have listed `/dir1/test.F90`, and that means that the `OBJS` variable will contain `/dir1/test.o`, and then you ask make to build `/dir1/test.o` it will compile it from the source file `/dir1/test.F90`.

If you put `/dir2/test.F90` in your `Srcfiles` file, then it will compile that into `/dir2/test.o`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks but it seems you don't understand my question. In the Srcfiles there is only test.F90 file name, how the compilation only compile /dir1/test.F90, while /dir2/test.F90 doesn't get compiled? Both /dir1/test.F90 and /dir2/test.F90 are included in the include directory.

Comment: If `Srcfiles` contains only `test.F90`, then this makefile cannot work.  So, clearly there's more to this makefile that you have not shared.  Thus we cannot help you.